# Share login session between different websites with different domain

Tags: php, authentication

I have 3 websites and it is necessary that each one of them has their own login form, but I'll check the same database in order to retrieve the user info, these 3 websites have their own domains. I have to share the session when a user signs in correctly to any of the login forms. I have read about SSO, so based on that I'm planning to do the following:

1.The action attribute of each login form will redirect to a central url that will check if there's an active session, doing something like:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
   //session is already set
}else{
   //there's no session
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   //search for this user in the database...
}
```

If there is no session, it will try to search for the user using the provided credentials and then begin the session.

2.After I set an active session I will redirect to the source url (but here I don't know how can I let know to any of the websites the session data I need such as name, username, etc.).

All websites are using PHP and each one of them are on different servers, am I following the right path for this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since the session will not persist if you just did a post request ( which I incorrectly suggested previously ), There is another way you can do it.

First have a secret key for each website. And on correct login, send this key in the get parameter to the source website. If the key matches then add the session to the source website.

But this method is prone to malicious interceptions. The best thing would be setting the logged in parameter in the database to true on login from central website, and checking the database from the source website.

Comment: I thought about that but, when making a POST request using something like CURL, when the user is redirected to the website that I made the curl request, and in the source website I do something like `echo $_SESSION['username'];`, will I get the right value?

Comment: Hmm the other option I can think of is that I can do another DB query in the source website, but I don't know if that's the best option I have